# how to create a variable in pandas dataframe based on another variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an issue where I have a dataframe data with multiple columns and I want to create a variable filter in the dataframe and assign the value 1 if activation_date is null else 0.

I have written this code but this is failing to get the results, everything is getting 0 irrespective if the dates are still present.

```
data['filter'] = [0 if x is not None else 1 for x in data['activation_dt']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for check `None` or `NaN`s and then convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` by `astype(int)`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'activation_dt':[None, np.nan, 1]})
print (data)
   activation_dt
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            1.0

data['filter'] = data['activation_dt'].isnull().astype(int)
print (data)
   activation_dt  filter
0            NaN       1
1            NaN       1
2            1.0       0
```